# gridview databind stops after processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I am having trouble with a GridView `DataBind` in C#. Whenever I run the `DataBind` method, it binds the data to the GridView, but then ignores any other commands I call after. I had no problem doing this with DataGrid's, but I'm not sure why it's not calling any of my functions after it binds.

I'm using `MessageBox.Show()` to confirm my suspicions (crude but effective). Is there something I should be looking for in the Debug or Breakpoints that can give me some indication of why it just stops processing once it finishes the `DataBind`?

Comment: Where are you calling these "other commands"? In which event handler? Can you show us the code that doesn't work?

Comment: "I had no problem doing this with DataGrid's, but I'm not sure why it's not calling any of my functions after it binds." --> Do you mean that before you do the `DataBind` operation, all the other commands work fine--then as soon as you `DataBind` they stop working?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

An unclosed tag, like a div, has caused me that same behaviour before. Check if they are ok.  Having duplicate IDs inside the grid has caused me this as well. For some reason being inside the gridview doesn't make the compiler raise any flags of duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Now I feel like a fool. I commented out the extra events from my GridView and it was able to finish processing.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You should really post the a) code in the original question b) the code in the (self supplied) answer showing the fix. Without this you are polluting stack overflow